Set an element's transform-origin based on the viewport in CSS
I have many elements positioned automatically around a page in various ways. I want to be able to transform each of them individually (not using a shared parent) with the center of transformation at the center of the viewport. The default transform-origin is the center of the element, and it seems like any values set are relative to its top left corner.
Here is an example situation:
<body>
    <p>paragraph1</p>
    <p>paragraph2</p>
    <p>paragraph3</p>
</body>

p {
    transform-origin: 50vw 50vh;
}
p.transform {
    transform: scale(2);
}

Setting transform-origin: 50vw 50vh would only give the desired effect on an element in the top left corner of the viewport. CSS doesn't allow for calculations based on computed styles, like the top and left of the element. transform-box only has options relative to the element itself. I can't put each element in an individual parent sized to the viewport, since many of them affect each other's position, others are in flexboxes, etc.
I'm sure this is easy in javascript, but I'd be surprised that something this relatively simple cannot be done in plain CSS.

you declare css p.transform. where is p tag which has class transform?

The idea is that I can add/remove the transform class (or otherwise put the scale on a pseudoclass) whenever needed.

It's not clear to me exactly what you are trying to achieve. I have added an answer based on what I imagine you might be attempting to do, but I could be on the wrong track. You say "I have many element positioned automatically around a page in various ways" -- can you include a screen shot of that? Then you say "I want to be able to transform each of them ...", but you don't explain why. What is the purpose of transforming them, the end goal? Please edit your post to clarify/illustrate.

By "positioned automatically around a page" I mean that they are part of a document flow, and I cannot take them out of that flow without affecting everything after them. In this case its paragraph elements with various positioning classes and flexboxes created per-page from markdown (kramdown) pages. The goal is to have all their transform origins in the same place while being able to transform them individually. Imagine each element scales away from the center of the body or viewport or a common parent on hover.

I would use absolute positioning or fixed positioning to solve this. When you assign a percentage value to the position (eg left or top) of an absolute/fixed positioned element, those values are relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (if there is one), or to the initial containing block (which is the same size as the viewport).
If you combine this with transform: translate(-50%, -50%) then the left and top positions will effectively refer to the centre of each element, rather than to its top left corner. Left effectively becomes cx – the horizontal centre, and top effectively becomes cy – the vertical centre.


img, p {
  position: fixed;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

img {
  width: 50px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.i1 {
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.i2 {
  left: 90%;
  top: 10%;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.i3 {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg) scale(1.5);
}

.i4 {
  left: 10%;
  top: 90%;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

.i5 {
  left: 90%;
  top: 90%;
  border: 3px solid gold;
}

.i6 {
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  border: 3px solid lime;
}

.i7 {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  border: 3px solid magenta;
}

.i8 {
  left: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  border: 3px solid pink;
}

.i9 {
  left: 0%;
  top: 100%;
  border: 3px solid cyan;
}

.p1 {
  left: 20%;
  top: 20%;
  background: red;
}

.p2 {
  left: 80%;
  top: 20%;
  background: green;
}

.p3 {
  left: 20%;
  top: 80%;
  background: blue;
}

.p4 {
  left: 80%;
  top: 80%;
  background: gold;
}
<img class="i1" src="https://picsum.photos/id/354/100">
<img class="i2" src="https://picsum.photos/id/355/100">
<img class="i3" src="https://picsum.photos/id/356/100">
<img class="i4" src="https://picsum.photos/id/357/100">
<img class="i5" src="https://picsum.photos/id/358/100">
<img class="i6" src="https://picsum.photos/id/360/100">
<img class="i7" src="https://picsum.photos/id/361/100">
<img class="i8" src="https://picsum.photos/id/362/100">
<img class="i9" src="https://picsum.photos/id/363/100">
<p class="p1">one</p>
<p class="p2">two two</p>
<p class="p3">three three three</p>
<p class="p4">four four four four</p>



After running this snippet, use the full page link to test the responsive behaviour.
